# is there a way to filter multiple segments in XML based on the field content in Groovy Script?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, scripting, xml-parsing

I have below XML that needs to be filtered

```
<Root>
    <Record>
        <EmployeeID>E1</EmployeeID>
        <LocationName>BLR</LocationName>
        <FirstName>Sriprsad</FirstName>
        <LastName>Bhat</LastName>
        <MiddleName>Shivaram</MiddleName>
        <EmailAddress>sri@test.com</EmailAddress>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmployeeID>E4</EmployeeID>
        <LocationName>GGN</LocationName>
        <FirstName>Praveen</FirstName>
        <LastName>R</LastName>
        <MiddleName>T</MiddleName>
        <EmailAddress>praveen@test.com</EmailAddress>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmployeeID>E3</EmployeeID>
        <LocationName>DEL</LocationName>
        <FirstName>Rahul</FirstName>
        <LastName>Singh</LastName>
        <MiddleName>Markand</MiddleName>
        <EmailAddress>rahul@test.com</EmailAddress>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmployeeID>E4</EmployeeID>
        <LocationName>CHN</LocationName>
        <FirstName>Marko</FirstName>
        <LastName>Chacko</LastName>
        <MiddleName>Kel</MiddleName>
        <EmailAddress>Marko@test.com</EmailAddress>
    </Record>
</Root>
```

My Groovy script needs to select 2 segments with EmployeeID E4. With my script I will only be able to select one segment. Please help.

```
def list=new XmlParser().parseText(body)  //considering that body is containing above XML
def nodeToDel=list.Record.find { it.EmployeeID.text() == 'E4' }
def parent = nodeToDel.parent()
parent.remove(nodeToDel)
def valid_data=XmlUtil.serialize(list)
def deleted_data=XmlUtil.serialize(nodeToDel);
println "${deleted_data}"
println "${valid_data}"
```

Comment: replace `find` with `findAll`

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Groovy Script, This helped me.